# Ada aspects which are private to a package

Tags: package, ada, preconditions

Let's say I have the stupidest ring buffer in the world.

```
size: constant := 16;
subtype T is integer;

package RingBuffer is
  procedure Push(value: T);
  function Pop return T;
end;

package body RingBuffer is
  buffer: array(0..size) of T;    
  readptr: integer := 0;
  writeptr: integer := 1;

  procedure Push(value: T) begin
    buffer(writeptr) := value;
    writeptr := (writeptr + 1) mod size;
  end;

  function Pop return T
  begin
    readptr := (readptr + 1) mod size;
    return buffer(readptr);
  end;
end;
```

Because my code sucks, I want to add preconditions and postconditions to make I don't misuse this sure. So I change the implementation of Push as follows:

```
procedure Push(value: T) with
  pre => readptr /= writeptr
is begin
  buffer(writeptr) := value;
  writeptr := (writeptr + 1) mod size;
end;
```

However, I get a compile error because I need to put the aspect definitions in the declaration of the procedure, not in the implementation.

The thing is, this is a package. My declaration is public. The values that the precondition is depending on belong to the package body, which isn't visible to the declaration. In order to put the aspect definition in the declaration I'm going to have to refactor my code to expose implementation details into the public part of the package (in this case, `readptr` and `writeptr`). And I don't want to do that.

I can think of a few ways round this, such as having my implementation of `Push()` call a private `PushImpl()` procedure defined only in the body which actually has the precondition... but that's horrible. What's the right way to do this?

Comment: A warning: The size of your buffer is `Size + 1`.

Comment: I did say it was the stupidest ring buffer in the world...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is always going to be a problem when the validation checks are private, and that the solution is to declare a function to do the check:

```
package RingBuffer is
   function Is_Full return Boolean;
   procedure Push(value: T) with Pre => not Is_Full;
   function Pop return T;
```

(`Is_Full` is probably useful anyway; in other cases it might not be so).

If you leave the implementation in the package body, you’ll need to put `Is_Full` there too, but you could move them to the spec and use an expression function:

```
package RingBuffer is
   function Is_Full return Boolean;
   procedure Push(value: T) with Pre => not Is_Full;
   function Pop return T;
private
   buffer: array(0..size) of T;
   readptr: integer := 0;
   writeptr: integer := 1;
   function Is_Full return Boolean is (Readptr = Writeptr);
end RingBuffer;
```

Comment: Yes, that'll work in this case, because the thing I'm checking is something which can be usefully exposed to the caller, but I can easily think of situations when it shouldn't be... This seems a very odd requirement; surely checking implementation is one of the things that invariants are _for_? In beginning to think that my plan for splitting the code into a public `Push()` and a private `PushImpl()` is the least bad way to do this.

Comment: It may be ugly, but to take the extreme case one could have a Boolean function `It_Is_OK_To_Call_Foo`, and the poor user could write `if It_Is_OK_To_Call_Foo then Foo else ....;`. In general, if you don’t expose something like this (but with a less silly name!), how is the user to know when they are about to violate the contract?

Comment: Well, as I said, in this case I'm not checking the external contact; I'm checking the internal contracts which are the implementation  invariants. None of this is the user's business.  the user should ever care about and so shouldn't be exposed. I can't be the first person who's wanted to do this, which is why I'm surprised at this requirement that they must be exposed.

Comment: Preconditions are to make sure the user isn’t trying to use the package wrongly; if violated it’s their responsibility, not yours. Invariants are to make sure you’ve implemented the package right (the postconditions will probably help the user know what to expect, to an extent). As it stands, the only implementation invariants I can see are that both `writeptr` and `readptr` must be in `0 .. size - 1` (and, as Jacob points out, you could achieve that by declaring them of `mod size`). There are postconditions on `Push` and `Pop` too (for example, after a `Push` the buffer won’t be empty).

Comment: .. and also, it’d be much more normal Ada to declare a private type `Buffer`; you can then attach a `Dynamic_Predicate` to the full declaration, thus keeping it away from the users’ eyes.

Answer (score 2):

The contract aspects are intended to be used in the public view of (sub)types and subprograms.

If you want to keep the check in the private view, then it is simple to write it as the first statement in the subprogram:

```
begin
   if Is_Full then
      raise Constraint_Error with "Ring buffer is full.";
   end if;
   ...
```

Some unsolicited advise:

- Make the contracts public, so the users of the package can see how it should be used.
- Insert a similar `Is_Empty` check when popping an item from the buffer.
- Make your index type modular: `type Indexes is mod 16;`